# HTML5 File Read and Write Synchronous

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have managed to setup code to write to and read from a text file.
The problem I've run into is when I try to read the file after writing it.
It returns a null value.
I am assuming this is due to the write not being complete when the read starts.
How do I make the read wait for the write.

MyFile Class

```
MyFile = function() {

};

MyFile.prototype.readFile = function(fileDir, fileName) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileDir, function(dir) {
        dir.getFile(fileName, {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function(file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onerror = function(evt) {
                    console.log("Reading " + file.name +  " Failed");
                };
                reader.onloadstart = function(evt) {
                    console.log("Read " + file.name +  " Starting");
                };
                reader.onload = function(evt) {
                    console.log("Read " + file.name +  " Successful");
                    window.localStorage.setItem(file.name + "Read", evt.target.result);
                    console.log(evt.target.result);
                };
                reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                    console.log("Read " + file.name +  " Ending");
                };
                reader.readAsText(file);
            }, fail);
        }, fail);
    }, fail);
    var strText = window.localStorage.getItem(fileName + "Read");
    console.log(strText);
    window.localStorage.removeItem(fileName + "Read");
    return strText;
};


MyFile.prototype.overWriteFile = function(fileDir, fileName, strText) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileDir, function(dir) {
        dir.getFile(fileName, {create: true}, function(file) {
            if (!file) {
                return;
            } else {
                console.log("Overwrite File Name: " + file.name);
            }
            file.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
                fileWriter.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                    if (fileWriter.length === 0) {
                        //fileWriter has been reset, write file
                        fileWriter.write(strText);
                    } else {
                        //file has been overwritten with blob
                        //use callback or resolve promise
                        console.log("Write " + file.name +  " Success");
                        console.log(strText);
                    }
                };
                fileWriter.truncate(0);
            }, fail);
        });
    });
};
```

Calling Write and Read

```
 var myf = new MyFile();
 myf.overWriteFile("Directory", "test.txt","Test.txt Contents");
 console.log(myf.readFile("Directory", "test.txt"));
```

Comment: Do you mind jQuery? the post is tagged with it but I don't see it in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont mind jQuery you can try using a custom event that you fire when the file is done writing.

```
MyFile.prototype.overWriteFile = function(fileDir, fileName, strText) {
    //added self var to be accessed from within createWriter finished section
    var self = this

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileDir, function(dir) {
        dir.getFile(fileName, {create: true}, function(file) {
            if (!file) {
                return;
            } else {
                console.log("Overwrite File Name: " + file.name);
            }
            file.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
                fileWriter.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                    if (fileWriter.length === 0) {
                        //fileWriter has been reset, write file
                        fileWriter.write(strText);
                    } else {
                        //file has been overwritten with blob
                        //use callback or resolve promise
                        //triggers the finishedMyFileWrite on the MyFile instance
                        jQuery(self).tigger('finishedMyFileWrite');
                        console.log("Write " + file.name +  " Success");
                        console.log(strText);
                    }
                };
                fileWriter.truncate(0);
            }, fail);
        });
    });
};

var myf = new MyFile();

jQuery(myf).on('finishedMyFileWrite', function finishedWrite(){
    console.log(this.readFile("Directory", "test.txt"));
});

myf.overWriteFile("Directory", "test.txt","Test.txt Contents");
```

I added a `self` variable to allow the custom event to target the specific instance of MyFile, then I trigger an event called `finishedMyFileWrite` after the file has written. The myf object is set to listen for this callback before writing.  I am not able to test this as I dont have a cordova emulator, but the theory should work.

Comment: This worked perfectly.
Is there a way to also set the readFile to not return data until the reader is done or is that done by the onload trigger?

Comment: You could try using a short setTimeout function to spin while it waits for the code to finish, or firing an event in the `reader.onloadend` that would tell you when the load is over.